# Unconfirmed transaction after long wait

Tags: blockchain.info

One of my transaction remain unconfirmed and I think I spent uncomfirm transaction.pls how can this be solved pls here is my transaction Id https://blockchain.info/tx/cd3d718dd370f7446f1b73c6a18c4441e0eb78a63bae6fb0964470e5fe872da3

Comment: It since confirmed.